# Selenium c# eventually doesn't Second assert condition

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, assert

Hi I was wondering where the logic went wrong as in the output selenium is asserting the first Condition, but not looking at second condition if the element displayed is pass or fail.

```
foreach (var element in options)
{
    if (element.Text.Contains("5/1, test road"))
    {
        element.Click();
        var Add = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ui-click__confirm"));
        Add.Click();
        Assert.Pass("Test has been selected from the list");
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.Fail("Test has not been selected from the list");
    }
    var AssociatedProperty = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ui-click__confirm--has-test"));
    if (AssociatedProperty.Displayed==false)
    {
        
        Assert.Fail("Test record has not passed");
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.Pass("Tenant record has passed");
    }
}
```

Comment: The second `By.CssSelector` contains two consecutive . symbol, is that correct? Then, are you sure that element exists and that `AssociatedProperty` is not null?

Comment: I think Marco is right. "..ui-click__confirm--has-test" is a bad selector and so By.CssSelector will throw a InvalidSelectorException. As a result, the for loop will end prematurely and you won't see a result from either of the second Asserts. Try checking what exceptions this produces and fixing the selector.

Comment: Hi Marco, Thanks for your reply, I have removed . symbol, the locator I have passed is correct, somehow in the question that was a wrong edit, rectified.

Comment: Yes the element exists in an article class not sure why the code is not asserting that condition if element is displayed.

Comment: None of the 2nd Assert are executed or you have the wrong one now?

Comment: None of the second assert are executed. It is executed till Add.click and gives the result in output. BUt not sure why its not picking up to execute Associate property

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified a unit testing framework, but asserts usually end the test whether the assertion fails, or you call `Assert.Pass(...)`. Essentially, the asserts throw an exception, which is caught by the unit testing framework. The unit testing framework will pass or fail the test based on the kind of exception.

In your case, I see multiple `Assert.Pass(...)` calls. Each of those will end the test, and mark it passed. That means the test runner does not execute any code beyond the `Assert.Pass` method call.

If you want your test to continue, omit the calls to `Assert.Pass`. Furthermore, it is idiomatic to test method or property return values in your assertions, rather than using and `if` statement followed by `Assert.Fail`.

This is probably how the code should look so it checks all of the conditions you want, while using a more typical coding style for tests:

```
foreach (var element in options)
{
    Assert.True(element.Text.Contains("5/1, test road"), "Test has not been selected from the list");

    element.Click();
    var Add = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ui-click__confirm"));
    Add.Click();
    var AssociatedProperty = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ui-click__confirm--has-test"));

    Assert.True(AssociatedProperty.Displayed, "Test record has not passed");
}
```

This code assumes NUnit for a unit testing framework. If this is not what you are using, please update your question so I can update my answer, but generally every unit testing framework will have some functionality like this.

Comment: Thanks, tried the code, result thrown stale element exception
Added implict wait still no luck
OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : stale element reference: stale element not found
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.64)

  Stack Trace: 
WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse, String commandToExecute)
WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
WebDriver.InternalExecute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
WebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
WebElement.get_Text()

Comment: @user21175930: that is a separate question. Now that your test is written in a more typical style, you've discovered a different issue that justifies a separate question.